# Single object iterator

Tags: python

To be consistent with an API, I have to **return** an iterator which yields exactly one value and then stops (it must be a correct value returned by `.__iter__()`). So far, I have:

```
return (myobject for _ in [0])
```

Is there a better (more "Pythonic") way to do this?

Comment: "More pythonic" does not mean "short" or even "less complicated." I don't know what you have against doing `def f(): yield myobject`.

Comment: I want to **return** a generator, so I would have to create `f` as you do, then to return it.

Comment: Yup, you would. And it's the most pythonic way to do that, because it's explicit and natural. Pythonic doesn't mean "tricky". Also: based on the comment made below your accepted answer, you in fact do NOT actually want a "generator".

Comment: You find it more pythonic, I don't :-)

Comment: No I find more pythonic to use `return (myobject for _ in [0])` instead of defining a function then returning it. That's my point of view and I think we can agree to disagree on that.

Comment: @Pierre, You don't need to define an additional function and return the return value of the function. Just replace the `return` statement with `yield`: `return (myobject for _ in [0])` => `yield myobject`

Comment: @falsetru This is not the same, you're defining a generator, I want to **return** it.

Comment: @falsetru That depends on what the function does otherwise. Maybe in other cases, it returns something else, and a `yield` at that level would make that impossible.

Comment: @Pierre No, the result is the same: he defines a generator function, which returns a generator as well.

Comment: @glglgl, I know. I requested OP to add information about that if there's multiple statements. But OP didn't.

Comment: @falsetru a naked `yield` doesn't seem to work in Python 3, at least: `def f(g): return next(g)` then `f(yield object())` produces a syntax error.

Comment: No, using `return (myobject for _ in [0])` **returns** a generator, while using `yield` in a function will make the function itself a generator.

Comment: @RickTeachey,  What do you mean `naked yield`? Did you see this? https://ideone.com/7uKAaV (run both in Python 3 and Python 2)

Comment: Yes that works for me - I thought you were suggesting using `yield` outside of the function body, "naked", in order to avoid making the generator and then returning an object reference to the generator. It wasn't working for me. But that's not what you were saying.

Comment: @Pierre Using `yield` in a function will make the function a *generator function*. To get a generator, you have to call it as well. You do `for i in f()`, not `for i in f`. So the result is essentially the same. See as well [here](https://ideone.com/jY8zR6).

Comment: Would be neat if you could make "lambda" generators. I guess the generator comprehension already serves this purpose though.

Comment: @RickTeachey agreed! That's why I asked the question initially, I was hopping such a thing existed and I just missed it.

Comment: @glglgl "essentially", except if the rest of the code uses a `return` statement with a value. That's why I stated "I have to return a generator" and highlighted "return".

Comment: @Pierre Ok, in this case you are absolutely right. I have as well used this technique one time or another...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use

```
return (myobject for _ in (0,))
```

or

```
return (myobject for _ in ".")
```

because the tuple or the string literal are statically allocated while instead `[0]` allocates a new fresh list each time.

Comment: Good point and upvote for avoiding allocating a new list every time.

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
def single_value(x): yield x
return single_value(myobject)
```

for getting a generator. Or the same with `single_value = lambda x: (i for i in (x,))`.

As an iterable would be ok as well, other options are

```
return iter([myobject])
return iter((myobject,))
```

And as even an iterable is fine,

```
return [myobject]
return (myobject,)
```

are even easier.

Comment: @Pierre That would be fine as well, if appropriate.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, though. The question should be changed.

Comment: A "generator" has a specific meaning. `(myobject,)` is a tuple, not a generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`yield` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement):

```
yield myobject
```

Calling the function will return a generator.

Comment: I want to *return* a generator. So an answer with `yield` would be: `def f(): yield myobject` then `return f` which I find more complicated than the `return (myobject for _ in [0])` expression

Comment: @Pierre, Try `type(the_function(..))`. It will return a generator object.

Comment: @Pierre, [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) is like a succint version of generator definition.

Comment: @Pierre: the moment you use `yield` in a function, the *function itself* will always return a generator. No need to use a nested function here..

Comment: I'm in a part of a function which always **returns** a generator. This part is the "simple case" of a more complicated function.

Comment: @Pierre, Could you update your question to include that information?

Comment: As my question already states "to be consistent with an API, I have to return a single object generator", I will highlight the "return".

Comment: @Pierre, So, do you mean there are multiple `return` statements? If so, you'd better mention that. Otherwise, you can use `yield` statement in place of the `return` statement.

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer encompasses all the good qualities of the answers given so far

```
>>> def f():
       yield from (x[0] for x in iter(itertools.repeat([myobject], 1)) if True)


>>> type(f())
<class 'generator'>
```

Comment: pretty sure this was a joke. i laughed.

Answer (score -2):

Just use what you have, it works fine:

```
(o for o in [myobject])
```

Returns a generator that yields one object.

EDIT: 6502's answer is better! Not using a list would be more efficient.

EDIT: This answer is no longer applicable since the question has been changed.

Comment: Actually my object is already known (`myobject` in my example).

Comment: Then just replace `object()` with `myobject`...?

Comment: So that's just the code from my question? I was asking for a better code if possible.

Comment: @Pierre It is not just the same code, it is slightly different.

Comment: It's not the same code but he's right that it's the same basic idea. My only point was what he had was clear and working. :) For the original question I would think actually making and returning the generator is clearer (assuming that's what he wanted, which it turns out it wasn't), but this works too.